# Differentiability of this picewise function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
f(x,y) = 0 & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{array}\right.$$

In order to verify if this function is differentiable, I tried to prove it by the theorem that says that if $\frac{∂f}{∂x}$ and $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ exist and are continuous at the point $(x_0,y_0)$, then the function is differentiable at this point. So I did:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0,0+h)-f(0,0)}{h} = 0$$

so we have that the partial derivatives at point $(0,0)$ is $0$. Now, if we take the derivative at $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and then take the limit of it as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, we can see if the derivatives are continuous or not. So here it is:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = \frac{y(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)}$$

but

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{y(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)} $$
does not exist (by wolfram alpha... but can anybody tell me an easy way to prove this limit does not exist? easier than taking the limit in different directions?), therefore the derivative is not continuous at $(0,0)$, so we can't say $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$, but for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ the function is continuous, as it is a quotient of continuous functions. So $f$ is at least differentiable at $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$.

Now, to verify differentiability at $(0,0)$ I think we must use the limit definition of differentiablity:
A function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ iff:
$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{f(0+h,0+k)-f(0,0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)}{\|(h,k)\|} = 0$$

Let's calculate this limit:

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{f(0+h,0+k)-f(0,0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)}{\|(h,k)\|} = \\ \lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{\frac{hk}{h^2+k^2}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} = \\ \lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{hk}{(h^2+k^2)\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

which I think, it's a limit that does not exist, therefore the function isn't differentiable at $(0,0)$

Comment: Why not first try continuity? If it were discontinuous it cannot be differentiable either, and the problem is done.

Comment: @guerlando The function is not differentiable. Follow Miguel's advice

Comment: @MiguelAtencia Nice, so since differentiability implies continuity, if the function is not continuous, then suppose it is differentiable. We arrive at a contradiction, because differentiability implies continuity. Therefore the function can't be differentiable. Nice argument. So, suppose the function is continuous. Then I need to verify things as I did, rigth? Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: 1) Shouldn't the limit of differentiability have just $f(h,k)$? 2) Why do I see $xy$ in the definition of $f$ whereas $f(h,k)$ has a $h^2k^2$?

Comment: Also, in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, you should have $f(0,h)$ not $f(0+h,0)$.

Comment: @MickG I've corrected your last 2 observations, but didn't understand the first one. Also, my limit still does not exist, rigth?

Comment: @MickG oh ok, I've spotted the first observation, typed $y$ instead of $0$. Already corrected.

Comment: Just word of advice: note that "partial derivatives exists and are continuous" is *not* a necessary, but a sufficient condition for differentiability. You should never expect to verify a stronger condition in order to imply the weaker one because the weaker one may well hold even if the stronger one doesn't. However, continuity is a necessary condition for differentiability, so if it is not continuous at some point, it cannot be differentiable here, which is to say, you can sometimes effectively *disprove* a stronger condition by disproving a weaker one.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I have taken the liberty of editing your post. I made your piecewise definition into a brace definition, as it's usually written on paper. I substituted your partial derivative symbols with the latex command `\partial`, since those symbols seem out of place in MathJax. I made your single `\dfrac` back into a `\frac`, because I found it better-looking to have the upper fraction smaller, so you can immediately see which is the numerator and which is the denominator, whereas if everything is the same size one may think the denominator is a fraction and the numerator isn't.

Comment: I also tried improving the alignment of the last limit via `amsmath` environments, but the fact that the starting thing is so damn wide made my attempts all vain :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in comments, your function $f$ is not continuous at the origin, since taking the limit from $y=ax$ yields:
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x,ax)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{xax}{x^2+a^2x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a}{a^2+1}\frac{x^2}{x^2}=\frac{a}{a^2+1},$$
which depends on $a$.

Let me remark a couple of things. The limit you are looking for an "easy way" of computing". Well, what is easier than taking limits along directions? I can't think of anything easier than that. Can you? If I think of limits, I think of polar coordinates or asymptotics, and of taking limits along directions. What else?

The final limit you can prove not to exist by saying that for it to exist you need $\frac{hk}{h^2+k^2}$ to tend to zero, otherwise the remaining $\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$ will make it shoot to infinity, and as I have remarked above this limit does not exist. Otherwise you take limits along directions, getting that along $k=ah$ the limit is that of $\frac{ah^2}{(a^2+1)h^2\sqrt{a^2+1}\sqrt{h^2}}=\frac{a}{(a^2+1)\sqrt{a^2+1}}\frac{h^2}{h^2|h|}$, which depends on $a$, and almost always goes to infinity.

As a bonus, you can check that the function with $x^2y^2$ instead of $xy$ would have been differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Take $y=ax$, $a=\textrm{const}$, and show, that $f$ is not continuous at origin.

Answer (score 1):

A function that is discontinuous at a point cannot be differentiable at that point.

Using a polar coordinate transformation with $x=\rho \cos \phi$ and $y=\rho \sin \phi$ we have $f=\frac12 \sin 2\phi$ for $\rho \ne 0$.

Then the limit of $f$ as $\rho \to 0$ can be any number between $-1$ and $1$ by choice of $\phi$.  Inasmuch as the limit does not exits, $f$ is not continuous at the origin and therefore cannot be differentiable there.